# Invalid number in scalar divide

Tags: python, neural-network

i'm trying to make a golf AI, but, after about 5 generations, when it is changing the weights, it says:

```
main.py:109: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in scalar divide
  wX = backward([startPos[0], startPos[1], holePos[0], holePos[1]], forward((startPos[0], startPos[1], holePos[0], holePos[1]), wX), forward((startPos[0], startPos[1], holePos[0], holePos[1]), wX) / (forward((startPos[0], startPos[1], holePos[0], holePos[1]), wX) / x_offset), wX)
```

It makes the output, NaN, that breaks the program.
I tried to verify if the values are 0 and changing them to 1, but it doesn't work.
Also, if you see that it would never work, please tell me the issue.

My code:

```
import numpy as np
import random
import os

os.system("clear")

def sigmoid(x):
  return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x))

startPos = (random.randint(-20, 20), 0)

holePos = (random.randint(-20, 20), 0)

dist = random.randint(10, 35)

def shoot(speed, startpos, holepos, dist, velocityX, velocityY):
  pos = startpos
  distance = dist
  while True:
    #print(f"Pos: {pos}, hole pos: {holepos}, velo X: {velocityX}, velo Y: {velocityY} \n")
    
    pos[0] += velocityX
    pos[1] += velocityY
    print(pos)
    dist -= speed
    if pos[1] <= 0:
      pos[1] = 0
      velocityY = 0
      speed -= 1
      velocityX -= 1
    else:
      velocityY -= 9.81

    if velocityX <= 0:
      velocityX = 0
    if speed <= 0:
      speed = 0

    pos1 = pos

    pos1[0] = int(pos1[0])
    pos1[1] = int(pos1[1])

    dist2 = int(dist)

    if pos1 == holepos and dist2 == distance:
      print("hole!")
      return 1 , 0, 0, 0
      break
    elif velocityX == 0 and velocityY == 0 and speed == 0:
      print("fail!")
      
      return 0, dist - distance, pos[0] - holepos[0], pos[1] - holepos[1]
      break

wX = [random.uniform(-2, 2), random.uniform(-2, 2), random.uniform(-2, 2), random.uniform(-2, 2)]
wY = [random.uniform(-2, 2), random.uniform(-2, 2), random.uniform(-2, 2), random.uniform(-2, 2)]
wS = [random.uniform(-2, 2), random.uniform(-2, 2), random.uniform(-2, 2), random.uniform(-2, 2)]

def forward(inp, w):
  output = 0

  for v in range(len(inp)):
    output += inp[v] * w[v]

  output = sigmoid(output)

  return output

def backward(inp, output, target, w):

  lr = 0.1

  error = -(output - target)

  for asd in range(len(inp)):
    w[asd] += inp[asd] * error * lr

  return w

for x in range(1000):
  print("|| Generation", x + 1, "||")

  startPos = [random.randint(-20, 20), 10]

  while startPos[0] == 0:
    startPos = [random.randint(-20, 20), 10]

  holePos = [random.randint(-20, 20), 5]

  while startPos[0] == 0:
    startPos = [random.randint(-20, 20), 10]

  dist = random.randint(10, 35)
  result, offset, x_offset, y_offset = shoot(forward((startPos[0], startPos[1], holePos[0], holePos[1]), wS), startPos, holePos, dist, forward((startPos[0], startPos[1], holePos[0], holePos[1]), wX), forward((startPos[0], startPos[1], holePos[0], holePos[1]), wY))

  if x_offset == 0:
    x_offset = 1
  if offset == 0:
    offset = 1

  startPos[1] = 10

  if result == 0:
    wS = backward([startPos[0], startPos[1], holePos[0], holePos[1]], forward((startPos[0], startPos[1], holePos[0], holePos[1]), wS), forward((startPos[0], startPos[1], holePos[0], holePos[1]), wS) / (forward((startPos[0], startPos[1], holePos[0], holePos[1]), wS) / offset), wS)

    print(startPos)
    
    wX = backward([startPos[0], startPos[1], holePos[0], holePos[1]], forward((startPos[0], startPos[1], holePos[0], holePos[1]), wX), forward((startPos[0], startPos[1], holePos[0], holePos[1]), wX) / (forward((startPos[0], startPos[1], holePos[0], holePos[1]), wX) / x_offset), wX)
      
  if y_offset == 0:
    y_offset = 1
    
    wY = backward([startPos[0], startPos[1], holePos[0], holePos[1]], forward((startPos[0], startPos[1], holePos[0], holePos[1]), wY), forward((startPos[0], startPos[1], holePos[0], holePos[1]), wY) / (forward((startPos[0], startPos[1], holePos[0], holePos[1]), wY) / y_offset), wY)
```